# Make the Play 1.x router work when the application's root is other than /

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am sure this is very easy to solve, but I am in a rush, and could not find a quick way

I have an app based on Play 1.2.5 and I wanted to run three instances of it on the same machine. They won't use `/` as root, but `/inst1/ /inst2/` and `/inst3/` respectively.

If I simply let them run like this, all the automatically created links such as the one for the static resources, as well as the one that map to controller actions fail, becuase they always point to `/`.

I thought `applciation.baseUrl` would solve this, but either I am not doing it right, or it is not the right thing.

How do I do this? I want to avoid adding a custom configuration property and prefixing every path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your application.conf:**

```
#
# Use this if you don't host your Play application at the root of the domain
# you're serving it from. This parameter has no effect when deployed as a
# war, because the path will be handled by the application server.
http.path=/inst1/
```

Comment: The only problem I can see with this is that each application will have to be bound on a different port. You will probably need a reverse proxy to do the routing accordingly.